# function in JS object executed successfully but getting alert for "undefined", what is Undefined here?

Tags: javascript

[image]Using function in Javascript object and executed successfully however getting alert for "undefined", what id Undefined here?

```
<html>
    <head>
    <title>Function in Javascript</title>
    <meta charset="utf-8"/>
    </head>
    <script src="jsObjects.js"></script>
    <script>
                // alert(human.name);
        // console.log(human.name);
        // console.log(human["5"]); //connot use . notation instead use [] notation like array
        // alert(typeof human.toDelete);
        alert(human.testfunc());
    </script>
    <body>
    </body>
    </html>
```

//creating simple javascript objecs

```
var human = {
    "name" :"Neanderthals",
    "legs": 2,
    "hand": 2,
    "origin":["Asia", "Africa"],
    5: "five",
    bool  : true,
    testfunc: function() {
        console.log("I am function in js object");
    }
}
```

Comment: Well, `testfunc` is not returning anything (so the return value defaults to `undefined`), what were you expecting?

Comment: i just want to execute function and do not want anything to return. Function should call, perform certain actions and end gracefully.

Comment: Ok, then if you don't want the undefined alert to come up, then don't use `alert`, just call the function alone

Comment: `alert` alerts the returned value of the function. so either return something or do not alert then. simple.

Comment: Does this means that every function when executes returns always "undefined"?

Comment: @sudeeppatel No. Please read about [`return`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Learn/JavaScript/Building_blocks/Return_values).

Comment: it is basics of programming I think. Read it and learn it and move on only after that

Comment: i just missed that i used two alerts, one in function  itself and other while calling and so got confused. silly mistakes

Comment: We've all been there. You learn from your mistakes, hopefully.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It says undefined because your function is not returning anything.

Example 1:

```
function myFunction() {
  return 1; 
}
alert (myFunction());
```

This will execute the function, which returns 1. That value is passed to alert as parameter, it displays '1'.

Note that the last line is equivalent to:

```
var result = myFunction();  //result = 1;
alert(result);              //alert(1);
```

Now, look at this:

```
function myFunction() {
   //nothing returned
}
alert(myFunction());
```

It will call the function, which doesn't return anything, so the result is undefined. And that undefined result is passed to the alert.
Last line is equivalent to:

```
var result = myFunction();  //result = undefined;
alert(result);              //alert(undefined);
```

**If you want to just execute the function without displaying the result, call it this way**:

```
myFunction();
```